# Error 1064 (42000) Bad Syntax - where?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, command-prompt

http://www.sendspace.com/file/txjcvd

Hi, new to PHP/MySql, trying to create a simple database of 25 items miscellaneous items with an: id, productname, productprice and stock quantity.

```
create table id(
   id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
   productname varchar(25) not null,
   prodprice int(11) not null,
   stockquant int(11) not null;
```

However I can't seem to figure out what part of the syntax is wrong?

Comment: MySQL should be giving you back an error message which tells you the first part of the query it doesn't understand.  It'll say like "incorrect syntax near 'unsigned auto_increment..." or the like.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: ah yes, error at line 1 it says.

Comment: scroll horizontally, there's a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Not at the end, there isn't.

Comment: whats ';' after the not null?

Comment: `;` is the ´finalizer of the command´ you are saying with it that the command came to an end. As the other said you have to accomplish the `create table` statement which is `create table NAME ( field1, field2...,field10 );`

Comment: @hduncan: For reference, "parenthesis" means `(` or `)`.  A "closing parenthesis" is the right one (`)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table id (
id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
productname varchar(25) not null, 
prodprice int(11) not null, 
stockquant int(11) not null
;
```

Shouldn't there be a ) before the ; to account for the ( after the first line id (? (as several others commented)

```
create table id (
id int(11) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
productname varchar(25) not null, 
prodprice int(11) not null, 
stockquant int(11) not null
);
```

Comment: Error Line 5 on your answer :(

Comment: ah I didn't realize it there was a **);** needed. Query ok! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

It is missing the parenthesis at the end. With it the statement works fine:

```sql
mysql>
 CREATE TABLE id(
    id INT(11) unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    productname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    prodprice INT(11) NOT NULL,
    stockquant INT(11) NOT NULL
 );
```

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```